# How to debug NullReferenceException in PresentationFramework?

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, treeview, nullreferenceexception

My .NET 4 application uses the WPF TreeView which I have enhanced to enable keyboard navigation and lazy loading, for example. My **problem** is that, very rarely, the exception shown below is thrown. This happened to me only once during months of development, and I have bug reports from several customers who also get this once in a while. It is so rare that I cannot change something, play around with the app for a while and know if the problem is gone or not.

But my main **question** is: the stack trace shows only Microsoft code, there is nothing from me in there. Is this a bug in .NET/WPF? And are there any chances of getting to the root cause?

```
Type: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: PresentationFramework
Stack trace:    at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Int32 index)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.FindNextFocusableItem(Boolean walkIntoSubtree)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.InternalPredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection direction)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.FocusChanged(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
  at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
  at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject focus, Int32 timestamp)
  at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
  at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetCollectionView(CollectionView view)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
  at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
  at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
  at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject contextElement)
  at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.RemoveAll()
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.ClearAllContainers(ItemsControl itemsControl)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.ClearContainerForItem(DependencyObject container, Object item)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.UnlinkContainerFromItem(DependencyObject container, Object item)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Remove(GeneratorPosition position, Int32 count, Boolean isRecycling)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanupRange(IList children, IItemContainerGenerator generator, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanupContainers(Int32 firstViewport, ItemsControl itemsControl)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
  at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Process_WM_SIZE(UIElement rootUIElement, IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
  at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.LayoutFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
  at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
  at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
  at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
Target: System.Windows.DependencyObject ContainerFromIndex(Int32)
Inner exception message:
```

Note: I have had this on my machine, too, which runs a fully patched Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've personally never uncovered a bug in WPF.  However, stepping into the WPF code has frequently enabled me to trace the source of the problem back to myself.

Here are some MSDN articles on how to enable debugging Framework source:

- [Visual Studio 2008 version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2010 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)

Link to all versions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting!

Comment: You linked to the VS 2008 description. Here is the MSDN article "How to: Debug .NET Framework Source" for VS 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Linking both is probably useful for those stuck on 2008.